# Enforce user to set Mfa before using services he's allowed to use

Tags: amazon

There is an answer to this question to this [link](https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-certified-solutions-architect-associate/discussion/-KWJNinbYkNpvvJUsxge/how-to-require-and-set-up-mfa-for-all-).

Is there a better way, a more automated way, instead of making the user go in the console and look for how to manage the authenticator?

What happens if after that he removes the authenticator?

Expected:

1. User tries to log in
2. Console asks for password change
3. Colsole asks for scanning the code and introducing the codes
4. User logs in with new password and the code from authenticator

Comment: I think that you need to explain your question and the context better. And this looks more like a pure AWS config question rather than a security question.

Comment: This might be a better question for someone on ServerFault to answer. https://serverfault.com/